# Is it possible to use one preprocessor's input into another preprocessor in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to do something like this...

```
#define INPUT (x = 3, y = 5)
#define MATH(add) ((add == 1) ? (INPUT.x + INPUT.y) : (INPUT.x - INPUT.y))

void main (void)
{
int add = MATH (1);
int subs = MATH (0);
}
```

Basically I want to simplify this...

```
#define x 3
#define y 5
#define MATH(add) ((add == 1) ? (x + y) : (x - y))

void main (void)
{
int add = MATH (1);
int subs = MATH (0);
}
```

Is this possible in **C** somehow?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  you may check preprocessed code with `-E` gcc option

Comment: Actually I am writing code for Avr Mcu.

Comment: I mean, could you provide a full example, actually I does not understand what do you want (You have some preprocessed file and you want to preprocess it again with other compiler? )

Comment: Your example of how you want to "simplify" things is much more complex than what you started with.  What is it that you're actually trying to do?  Why use macros at all?  Just `int add = 3 + 5;` ... `int subs = 3 - 5;` would be simpler, I would think.

Comment: @Suprovo That doesn't really explain what you're trying to do! What is the goal of using these macros? (And don't just say "doing math".)

Comment: Preprocessor tricks: Just say no until you reach level 9

Comment: `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: My compiler "WinAVR" supports void main (void) .

Comment: What does "Level 9" mean? 
[chqrlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to do cpp drugs so badly, here is some food for thought:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x 3
#define y 5
#define x1 +
#define x0 -
#define MATH(a) x x##a y

int main(void) {
    int add = MATH(1);
    int subs = MATH(0);

    printf("add=%d, sub=%d\n", add, subs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir Actually I know this process...
I am exactly searching for my mentioned imaginary process in my question... Because I am trying to define my "AVR MCU's" port & pin in "WinAVR" simply, as it is simple in "CVAVR". I don't want to to use many "#define" because it looks bulky & memory is limited.

Comment: @Suprovo: you might want to write a more detailed explanation about AVR MCUs for those of us who don't have a clue... Note that macros do not use any memory in the target system.

Comment: @Suprovo you should avoid using preprocessor logic for program logic, if only because it will lead to duplicated code (instructions) which bloats your program. Better to use many more `#define` of constant values which do not incur any such penalty. Note that the defines don't consume memory if they are not used, and if they are even then with simple expressions constant folding will give you the most optimal code (compile with optimisations, like `-Os`) for coding access to hardware registers of GPIO, timers etc.